# How to push viewcontroller correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, ios9

This is my storyboard:
[image]

Short Description:

- My App starts with the LaunchController
- a modal segue shows the Reveal View Controller
- this bring the Menu Controller and my Main Navigation Controller (ID
  "NavController"; green Navbar) together. this will create a slide
  menu. (Basic Code:
  appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/)
- my Main Navigation Controller shows a TableViewController.
- this one have a menu button (3 Lines) which make the slide menu
  visible
- the plus icon willo push the last view Controller (ID: "VC1").

My Problem:
I would like to set quick actions for my app.
This code help works for that:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func handleShortcut( shortcutItem:UIApplicationShortcutItem ) -> Bool {

        var succeeded = false

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

        let navVC = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

        switch shortcutItem.type {

        default:
            navVC.pushViewController(storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC1"), animated: false)
            succeeded = true
            break
        }
        return succeeded

    }
```

This Code set the NavController as initial Controller und push the to VC1.
This works fine.

With the X icon in VC 1, i use the unwind function back to TableView.
The Problem: if i use the undwind function and fall back to tableview i can't open the slide menu. A Touch on the menu icon give no reaction.

The Problem can be, that i start the app with the quick action behind the Reveal View Controller.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Ghost108, have you now a solution for your problem ? can you share it for all please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make the reveal view controller the entry point of your app and deleting the launch controller, because if you just want to go back to the main view you could just do this :

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController!
    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

If you cannot could you explain the purpose of the launch controller?

Comment: the launch controlle can not be delete. can you show me the full code for my solution with my example of post 1